# How to get selected value in dropdown using Formik Field in React JS?

Tags: reactjs

```
export class SelectFruitModal extends Component {
FruitList = ['Apple', 'Mango', 'Chickoo', 'others'];
FruitListItems = this.FruitList.map((fruit) => <option key={fruit}>{fruit}</option>);
handleChange(event){
alert('Event',event.target.value)
}
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Modal>
                <ModalBody>
                    <Formik
                        initialValues={{
                            FruitList: ''
                        }}
                        render={({}) =>
                            !isSubmitting ? (
                                <div>
                                    <Row>
                                        <Form>
                                            <Row>
                                                <Col>
                                                    <div className="form-group">
                                                        <Field
                                                            name="FruitList"
                                                            component="select"
                                                            className={
                                                                'form-control' +
                                                                (errors.FruitList &&
                                                                    touched.FruitList
                                                                    ? ' is-invalid'
                                                                    : '')
                                                            }
                                                            onChange={this.handleChange}

                                                        >
                                                            <option disabled="disabled" value="">
                                                                Select fruit
                                                                    </option>
                                                            {this.FruitListItems}
                                                        </Field>
                                                    </div>
                                                </Col>
                                            </Row>
                                        </Form>

                                    </Row>
                                </div>
                            ) : (
                                    <PageSpinner />
                                )}
                    />
                </ModalBody>
            </Modal>
        </div>
    );
}
```

}

export default SelectFruitModal;

1.In above code I have dropdown of FruitList

2.My requirement is when I select others value from the fruitlistItems then I should get one textArea beside it.

3.For that I need to get selected value from dropdown as 'others' so that i can enable field textbox.

4.How can I get selected value of dropdown ? I tried using onChange() and calling event value in it gives me empty value. Please help?

Comment: Can you provide some working playground?

Comment: Hey I have changed the code you can have a look, I have added onChange() on dropdown,now I want to get selected value of dropdown in handleChange() method.

Comment: Where does Field come from? What framework is this?

Comment: Formik is a library-https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/field, you can have a look

Comment: I tried it myself in a playground, and i'm getting the correct event.target.value

Comment: are you getting selected value of dropdown,Note: please dont try to access value into onSubmit I want to access selected value in handleChange() method

Comment: can you send me the working code that you tried? or link of working code where i can see how it works?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209211/discussion-between-shraddha-agarwal-and-i-brod).